# How to use parse same json response in android when data is string instead of object?

Tags: android, json, observable, retrofit2

When i am getting response success class works perfectly. But when it is fail it gave me error.

Response when fail data pass in URL :

```
{
  "success": -1,
  "message": "Invalid username or password",
  "data": ""
}
```

Response when correct data pass in URL:

```
{
  "success": 1,
  "message": "User successfully logged in",
  "data": {
    "userId": 219,
    "userName": "mp",
    "picture": "219.png",
    "isBo": false,
    "isPo": true,
    "isHm": true,
    "hmProfileCompletionStatus": 3,
    "poProfileCompletionStatus": 2,
    "poPhoto": null,
    "hmPhoto": null,
    "custStripeToken": "xxx",
    "accountStripeToken": "xx",
    "bgcStatus": true,
    "idCardStatus": true,
    "isInsured": null,
    "amISponsered": false,
    "hmRating": null,
    "poRating": null,
    "email": "xxx@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

**UserResponse.java**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserResponse{
    private int success;
    private String message;
    private User data;
}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 64 path $.data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not possible. In your case it should be like this

```
{
  "success": -1,
  "message": "Invalid username or password",
  "data": {}
}
```

Ask your backend service team to change it with an empty object so that the same reponse object can be re used

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem statement you need to make generic type for response .Instead of  type **User** for 'data' object in **UserResponse.Class** make it **Object** type like this:-

```
  @Getter
  @Setter
  public class UserResponseCustom{
  private int success;
  private String message;
  private Object data;// modified for any type of data
  }
```

On webservice call,check whether data is instance of User or not,           that's it.

Now you can  have a check whether it is object or not

```
    if (userResponseCustom.getData() instanceOf User)

 /*userResponseCustom is supposed to be object of UserResponseCustom 
 which you are getting from server*/

  {
    // it's an object

    // do whatever you want with data as User Object
   }
  else
   {
    // it is an string, handle it
   }
```

Comment: Edited my answer as per your problem statement

Comment: Yes u are right but i m not manually convert json string to class. I have retrofit library where observable method automatically parse this data than again same issue.